# Docker can not run on Windows 10 linux child system

Tags: windows, ubuntu, docker, windows-10

I just install the Windows 10 Anniversary update which has a new feature that linux child system. So I try to run docker in Windows 10 ubuntu bash(linux child system). Why I want to install docker in linux child system is because:

1. Windows 10 native docker 1.12 need Hyper-V, but `Vmware` couldn't run if Hyper-V enable. I have a lot images created by `Vmware`, it isn't so easy to switch to Hyper-v
2. I don't want to use `Docker Toolbox`, it need install `VirtualBox`, just redunant.

---

apt-get is fine, docker install success, but fail to start.

```
$ sudo service docker start
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
 * Starting Docker: docker                                                   [ OK ]

$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

I have seen this post [can-you-run-docker-natively-on-the-new-windows-10-ubuntu-bash-userspace](https://serverfault.com/questions/767994/can-you-run-docker-natively-on-the-new-windows-10-ubuntu-bash-userspace), some people says that it is no posible to run docker in such linux child system, but there also some contrary opinions.

So, I want to ask is there any way to walk around this? Or I have to wait MS update this child system(since it is still beta now).

Answer (score 0):

You have two Problems in there:

1. the linux child system does not provide the upstart service like e.g. ubuntu. You can work around this by running the docker deamon directly in foreground with `docker daemon ...`
2. This does nearly shure not work because docker requires features of the linux kernel like namespaces and capabilities. I don't think the NT-Kernel does implement such exotic features.